# Magento 2 - Get country name from country code

Tags: magento2, php, layout, magento2.2, country-regions

I want to get country name from country code, in Magento 1.9 I use the code like this to get country name:

```
$countryCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/country_api')->items();
foreach($countryCollection as $key=>$val) {
    $countryCodes[$val['country_id']] = $val['name'];
}
```

How I can made this code to work for Magento 2?

I get the values from the multiselect attribute with the name country_iso_list, the values of this attribute are AD, AE, AF, AG ...ZW, so they are countries code. I just want to replace the country code with the country name in the frontend. So all I just need is to replace the this part of code:

```
echo $countryCodes[$val];
```

in this code

```
         $data = explode(',',$block->getProduct()->getData('hed_country_iso_list'));
                    foreach($data as $value):            
                        $attr = $block->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('country_iso_list');
                        if ($attr->usesSource()): 
                                $countries = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($value);
                                $ccode = explode(', ', $countries);
                        endif;
                    endforeach;
                    if (!empty($countries)):
                             echo "<p>"./* @escapeNotVerified */ __('This product can be sent to the following countries:')."</p>";
                             $k=0;
                             echo "<p>";
                             foreach($ccode as $key=>$val) {
                                    echo $countryCodes[$val];
                                    echo (++$k < sizeof($ccode)) ? ', ' : '';
                             }
                             echo "</p>";
                    endif;
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi @MuhammadHasham thank you for your help, I edit my answer to understand much better what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

  $country = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Directory\Model\Country')->load('AE')->getName();
```

**It is an example replace your country code with 'AE'**

> or To get country collection according to store, you need to add
>   following code in your file:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\YourModule\Block;

class country extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $_countryCollectionFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\CollectionFactory $countryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->Customer = $customer;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_countryCollectionFactory = $countryCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function getCountryCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_countryCollectionFactory->create()->loadByStore();
        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve list of top destinations countries
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getTopDestinations()
    {
        $destinations = (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'general/country/destinations',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
        return !empty($destinations) ? explode(',', $destinations) : [];
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve list of countries in array option
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCountries()
    {
        return $options = $this->getCountryCollection()
                ->setForegroundCountries($this->getTopDestinations())
                    ->toOptionArray();
    }
}
```

> Another simple way of doing it

Add code in your controller :

```
protected $_country;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Directory\Model\Country $country
 ) {
$this->_country = $country;
}

public function getCountryname() {
$countryCollection = $this->_country->getCollection();
foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
   echo "Country name:".$country->getName();
   echo "Country code:".$country->getCountryId();
}
}
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 3):

Try below code.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
)
{
    $this->countryFactory = $countryFactory;
}

public function getCountryName($code)
{
    $_country = $this->countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($code);
    if($_country)
    {
        return $_country->getName();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: for your effort. +1